# Connecting the declared input variables (global) to ExecComp

Tags: openmdao

Is there a way to connect the global input variables i.e.

```
def initialize(self):
    self.options.declare('num_elements', types=int)
```

to an execcomp?

```
prob.model.add_subsystem('paraboloid', ExecComp('f = num_elements*3 + c'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any way to connect to a declared option. The only things you can connect to are variables that were added inside components with `add_input` or `add_output`. I think in this case, since `num_elements` isn't meant to change, you should use a string expression to put the value into the ExecComp -- something like:

```
prob.model.add_subsystem('paraboloid', ExecComp('f = %d*3 + c' % num_elements))
```

where `num_elements` is a variable in your top level script.